# Font Awesome icon with the same unicode

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome

I want to use the Font Awesome icon "**file-lines**".
The link of the desired icon is this: https://fontawesome.com/icons/file-lines?f=classic&s=regular.
The problem is that the unicode of this the **solid version** is the same of the **regular version**! https://fontawesome.com/icons/file-lines?f=classic&s=solid

**f15c**

How can I choose the regular version in the css?

Edit: this topic is not duplicated. I searched it for this. And both icons are free: https://fontawesome.com/search?q=file%20lines&o=r&m=free

```css
.menu-nav a::before {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 0;
    content: '\f15c';
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    padding-right: 8px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-nav">
<a href="">Link 01</a>
</div>
```

Comment: font-weight is the difference but the regular is a pro one so you cannot use it

Comment: Hi, but they are both free: https://fontawesome.com/search?q=file%20lines&o=r&m=free

Comment: the font family is wrong, see the duplicate to know how to define the font-weight and font-family

Comment: read this: https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/setup/upgrade/pseudo-elements#contentHeader